Remove extra vertical space for just one column when using \cmidrule for other columns in a table
I would like to achieve that if I have a table and use \cmidrule, only the entries in the columns without \cmidrule do not use any vertical extra space. I have already seen this successfully in a scientific publication (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.enbuild.2024.114011). Here you can see that there is no extra space between ‘Dependence on at least one’ and ‘boundary condition’ in the third column:

My attempt to reproduce this (with the extra space that I would like to remove) and thus my current MWE is as follows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \toprule
        Flexibility activation & Dependence on at least one & Performance indicators \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
        Penalty- & Simulation of a DR & boundary condition\\
        aware & reference events & \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


How can I remove the extra vertical space between lines 1 and 2 of the third column so that the entries from the third column have no extra spacing? However, the extra spacing in the first two columns with the \cmidrule should be retained.

Ah, it was a long day yesterday... sorry for the faulty text entries in the table :-)'

Instead of manually splitting your text into multiple cells, merge the two cells:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{3.2cm}p{4.1cm}p{3.55cm}}
        \toprule
        Flexibility activation & Dependence on at least one & \multirow{2}{=}{Performance indicators boundary condition} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
        Penalty aware & Simulation of a DR reference events & \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}



This replicates the OP's (faulty) code rather than the screenshot they say they want to replicate.

@Mico As I understand the question, they want to remove the extra vertical space between Performance indicators and boundary condition, that's what this answer does.

Thanks, this helped! And sorry for the text errors in the table, I was quite tired when I posted my question :-)'

@TeXlearner You're welcome!

In {NiceTabular} of nicematrix, you can merge cells with the built-in command \Block:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    Flexibility activation & Dependence on at least one 
                  & \Block{2-1}{Performance indicators\\ boundary condition} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
    Penalty- & Simulation of a DR \\
    aware & reference events & \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Thanks a lot! I wasn't aware of this and will keep it in mind for future projects! :-)

I suggest creating a dedicated macro, say
\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\hsize}@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

to typeset the material in the third column. I would also switch from l to p column types for all three columns to allow automatic line breaking. In addition, I'd suppress full justification of the material in all three columns.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \cmidrule, and \midrule macros
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\smash[b]'
\usepackage{array}    % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}} % suppress full justification
\newcommand\mytab[1]{% 
   \smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}P{\hsize}@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} P{2.5cm} P{3cm} P{4cm} @{}} % choose suitable column widths
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Flexibility activation} & 
    \mytab{Dependence on at least one boundary condition} \\  
    \cmidrule(r){1-2}
    Penalty-aware control & 
    Simulation of a DR reference event  \\
    \midrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Thanks a lot! Although I decided to implement the other solution due to its shortness, I will take quite a bit of inspiration from this answer.
